# jquery not working on angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular

So I'm working on this template on angular which requires many custom jquery files.
 I did the 'npm install jquery' and added all the needed files in .angular-cli.json like this :

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "assets/js/popper.min.js",
    "assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/counterup/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/counterup/apear.js",
    "assets/vendors/counterup/countto.js",
    "assets/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/parallaxer/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js",
    "assets/vendors/tweet/tweetie.min.js",
    "assets/vendors/tweet/script.js",
    "assets/js/theme.js"
  ],
```

I'm not getting any errors but it's not working, it seems like the js files are not called.
Any help?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console of the web browser when you view the app?

Comment: What's not working? There is no code shown. Please take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: Can you provide code showing your template and how you are using jQuery in your component class that goes along with it?

Comment: try to reference it directly to your `index.html`

Comment: @JasonAller no there's no errors in the console

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I tried it, still not working.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I have a menu bar(simple html code) that is supposed to be fixed while scrolling and I know that the jquery.min.js file is responsible for it but it it's not working

Comment: Are you familiar with your browser's network tab which is often located in the developers tools near the console? Can you see if these JavaScript files are being loaded at all?

Comment: Where are you setting up the jQuery stuff in your code? e.g. in the `ngOnInit()` method, or constructor, etc

Comment: sorry I didn't notice... I'm getting 'ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined' on my console while I have installed the jQuery plugin and I have the jquery folder in the node_modules

Comment: so for now I added '<script type = "text/javascript" src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>' I have no more errors on my console but the jquery files are still not loaded